# Set list elements to 0 from an index to the end if partial sum is under certain value

Tags: python

Having a list of numbers, say:

```
numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2]
```

How could I write a function f that takes the list and a value and returns these results (I think the examples explains better):

```
f(numbers, 4)
[4, 0, 0, 0]

f(numbers, 3)
[0, 0, 0, 0]

f(numbers, 10)
[4, 5, 0, 0]

f(numbers, 17)
[4, 7, 7, 0]
```

I need to update the list with zeros from and index i such that sum(l[0:i]) <= val and sum(l[0:i+1]) > val.

I tried:

```
def f(numbers, val, last_index=-1):
    if sum(numbers[0:last_index]) > val:
         numbers[last_index] = 0
         last_index -= 1
         f(numbers, val, last_index)
```

I need to mutate the objects contained in the list. Not allowed to make copies. The function I've written does not work.

Comment: Are you trying to mutate the list or return a new list? You use the word "return" but your function returns nothing. What does "it does not work" mean? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: f(numbers, 17) isn't the output for this should be [4, 5, 7, 0]?

Comment: @HashirIrfan 4 + 5 + 7 = 16 < 17 and 4 + 5 +7 + 2 = 18 > 17

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm trying to mutate the objects contained in the list, the real problem is with a list of objects that have a field that would get updated after I run this function.

Comment: Why are you using recursion when a simple loop is more than adequate?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use recursion for this, a simple loop is sufficient.

This seems to do the trick, without creating copies of the input array.

```
def f(numbers, val):
    sum = 0
    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        if sum + number > val:
            numbers[i : ] = [0] * (len(numbers) - i)
            return numbers
        else:
            sum += number

numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2]
print(f(numbers, 4))
numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2]
print(f(numbers, 3))
numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2]
print(f(numbers, 10))
numbers = [4, 5, 7, 2]
print(f(numbers, 17))
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
[4, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 5, 0, 0]
[4, 5, 7, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a loop with `enumerate` rather than recursion:

```
def f(nums,target):
    total = 0
    for i,n in enumerate(nums):
        if total <= target: total += n
        if total > target:
            nums[i:] = [0]*(len(nums)-i)
            break
```

passes all of your test cases (after the typo is removed from the last).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because when you do slice `numbers[:last_index]` (you can omit zero) it return the list from index 0 to len(numbers)-2, not len(numbers)-2, so you can fix it doing the following:

```
def f(numbers, val, last_index=0):
    if not last_index:
        last_index = len(numbers) -1
    if sum(numbers[0:last_index]) > val:
         numbers[last_index] = 0
         last_index -= 1
         f(numbers, val, last_index)
```

And now it will works. But your code is inefficient, you should look another way, cause you are doing a sum of slices avery time. Here is another option:

```
def f(numbers, val):
    s=0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if s + l[i] <= val:
            s  += l[i]
        else:
            for j in range(i, len(l)):
                l[j] = 0
```